global.fetch not available in jest environment
I had to migrate from create-react-app to Vite for a current project and thus have to configure Jest for my tests to run.
My app uses apollo client for communication to the graphQl server.
Running the tests throws an error in the client.ts (configuration for apollo client). It points to the issue that fetch is undefined. That's expected, since Jest overrides the globals in its environment.
I've found out you can add globals in the jest config or add a fetch implementation in a Jest setupFile.
Here is my Jest config
const config = {
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  preset: "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts-esm",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // nothing interesting here
  },
  reporters: [
    "default",
    ["jest-junit", { outputDirectory: "./coverage", outputName: "junit.xml" }],
  ],
  coverageReporters: ["text", "cobertura", "html"],
};

export default config;

Adding globals like:
globals: {
    fetch: global.fetch,
  },

leads to passing tests, if run in band or run one by one (i.e. running a specific test suite)
However running multiple tests in parallel still leads to the fetch being undefined in the tests and thus test failures.
If I configure a setup file for example like:
import fetchMock from "jest-fetch-mock";

fetchMock.enableMocks();

using jest-fetch-mock library or:
import "whatwg-fetch";

using the whatwg-fetch library and adding it to the jest.config.js like so:
// somewhere in the config
setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/pathToMySetupfile.js"],

leads to hanging tests after a certain amount of passed tests. The test script keeps on running, but the tests do not continue. Worthwhile mentioning that this solution works for all the tests that have run up this point (fetch is defined).
Has anyone had similar issues and has a solution to my problem?
